# Is there a way we can query using .find to take key as array of input

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to provide array in filter of .find method
I found this method which matches a string in an array of input , Is there a way we can do It other way round .
`db.collection.find({"phoneNumber.type": { $in: ["ACD", "BFG"] } })`

Comment: Try using the `$eq` operator.

Comment: probabaly not .I want something like 
db.collection.find({ ['a','b','c'] : 'c'  })
where it matches the 3 array item and return that matching field

Comment: Can you add a collection example and expected output?

Comment: Is not a simple `$or` what you need? https://mongoplayground.net/p/egLZ1EUpJze

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment where you are looking for something like: `db.collection.find({ ['a','b','c'] : 'c' })` I think you can use this aggregate query:

- First create an auxiliar field using `$objectToArray` to get keys as `k` field and value as `v` field.
- Then `$match` using `$in` with keys. This `$match` return the documents where the key is in the array (in this case `["a", "b", "c"]`) and value (`v`) is desired one. Also `$elemMatch` is used to ensure the object is the same.
- And the last step is `$project` to remove the auxiliar field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "aux": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "aux": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "k": {"$in": ["a","b","c"]},
          "v": "c"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "aux": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qxi3E4kvd7x)

Comment: While this would technically work, it would require read every document in the collection and performing work for each, and would not be able to use an index for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically build an array of criteria on the client side:

```
const fieldnames = [ "field1","field2","field3" ];
const value = "match";
const criteria = fieldNames.map(function(fname){
    var ret = {};
    ret[fname] = value; 
    return ret;
});
```

Then if you want documents where *any* of them match, use:

```
Model.find({$or: criteria})
```

If you only want documwents were *all* of them match, use:

```
Model.find({$and: criteria})
```